# For each loop with JSON object python

Tags: python, json

Alright, so I'm struggling a little bit with trying to parse my JSON object.
My aim is to grab the certain JSON key and return it's value.

**JSON File**

```
{
  "files": {
    "resources": [
      {
        "name": "filename",
        "hash": "0x001"
      },
      {
        "name": "filename2",
        "hash": "0x002"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've developed a function which allows me to parse the JSON code above

**Function**

```
def parsePatcher():
    url = '{0}/{1}'.format(downloadServer, patcherName)
    patch = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(patch.read())
    patch.close()
    return data
```

Okay so now I would like to do a foreach statement which prints out each name and hash inside the `"resources": []` object.

**Foreach statement**

```
for name, hash in patcher["files"]["resources"]:
    print name
    print hash
```

But it only prints out "name" and "hash" not "filename" and "0x001"

Am I doing something incorrect here?

Comment: Note that JSON is a *transportation format*. Once parsed, all you have is Python objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `name, hash` as the `for` loop target, you are *unpacking* the dictionary:

```
>>> d = {"name": "filename",  "hash": "0x001"}
>>> name, hash = d
>>> name
'name'
>>> hash
'hash'
```

This happens because iteration over a dictionary only produces the keys:

```
>>> list(d)
['name', 'hash']
```

and unpacking uses iteration to produce the values to be assigned to the target names.

That that worked at all is subject to random events even, on Python 3.3 and newer with hash randomisation enabled by default, the order of those two keys could equally be reversed.

Just use *one* name to assign the dictionary to, and use subscription on that dictionary:

```
for resource in patcher["files"]["resources"]:
    print resource['name']
    print resource['hash']
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the perfect solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

So what you intend to do is :

```
for dic in x["files"]["resources"]:
    print dic['name'],dic['hash']
```

You need to iterate on those dictionaries in that array resources.

Answer (score -2):

The problem seems to be you have a list of dictionaries, first get each element of the list, and then ask the element (which is the dictionary) for the values for keys name and hash

EDIT: this is tested and works

```
mydict = {"files": { "resources": [{  "name": "filename",  "hash": "0x001"},{  "name": "filename2",  "hash": "0x002"}]} }

for element in mydict["files"]["resources"]:
  for d in element:
    print d, element[d]
```

Answer (score -2):

If in case you have multiple files and multiple resources inside it. This generalized solution works.

```
for keys in patcher:
     for indices in patcher[keys].keys():
             print(patcher[keys][indices])
```

Checked output from myside

```
for keys in patcher:
...     for indices in patcher[keys].keys():
...             print(patcher[keys][indices])
...
[{'hash': '0x001', 'name': 'filename'}, {'hash': '0x002', 'name': 'filename2'}]
```

Comment: Ah, no, it'll work, but not produce the desired output. The OP already got this far, they *already have that list*. You created a elaborate loop version of  the `patcher["files"]["resources"]` expression without looping over that list.

Comment: i'm not saying your answer is wrong, i generalized for multiple elements... for that loop should be used...